# CSS 'Content footer' sticks to the bottom when content doesn't exceed scrollheight but flows with content when it does

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

this is a tricky one...

Say if I have the following: (see diagram).

If the content + 'content footer' does not exceed the scrollheight I need the 'content footer' to be positioned at the bottom of the page. (See image, example A)

If the content + 'content footer' exceeds the scrollheight, Then as the content increases, I want to have the 'content footer' flow after the main content just as if it were another block element, but be the full width of the page. (See image example B)
[image]

Comment: Just do 

position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width 100%;
height: 50px; // Whatever height you want.

Set a background, and vuala :D

Comment: These are two questions in one.  
You 'd be better off, if you split them in two Posts.

Comment: I've read your post several times and I don't understand the effect you want to achieve, even with the images. Can you try rewording it?

Comment: Hi Michael, I've tried to make it clearer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be made with flex

http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/GpaxNJ

```css
#content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

#content {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 20px;
}
#actual-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

#content-footer {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body,html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content-footer">Content Footer</div>
</div>
<div id="actual-footer">Actual Footer</div>
```

---

> edit

If flex is no good, you should try using display `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell`

Answer (score 0):

I've got a breakout CSS here: http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/PqjBrg

It works by wrapping the content-footer with two divs
`<div class="breakout"><div class="breakout_back">` with the style

```
.breakout {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
}
.breakout .breakout_back {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
}
```

This is only compatible with browsers which support 100vw (view width) units: 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

---

A different strategy would be: Every content has 100% width by default. And every content should deal with it's width for itself

Comment: Why is this better than a fixed width div, followed by a 100% width div containing a fixed width div, followed by another fixed width div? There's a downside of less support. Are there any upsides?

Comment: @Michael Maybe I didn't understand the question in it's entirety. But I think fixed content is not what the OP wants to have.

Comment: I don't think I did either. But assuming your answer is correct, why not just do: https://jsfiddle.net/hycqspgc/ ?

Comment: @Mich that's what I said below the <hr>. But I think this would be to much work for the OP to reorganize the layout styles.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion HerrSerker, This is almost what I have but I cant get it to stick to the bottom initially when the content + content footer doesn't exceed the scrollheight. Apologies for the initial confusing question (Well done for interpreting it as was)